# ipopt: how efficient is -Inf < var < Inf when defining a decision variable in ipopt?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, ipopt

I am using ipopt to solve trajectory optimization problems and would like to know the difference (in terms of efficiency) between setting the bounds of a decision variable as 1) any real number, `(-Inf,Inf`) and 2) any "large" real number, e.g. `(-10^12,10^12`). I use quotation marks here because "large" is subjective and depends on the application.

Choosing `10^12` as my "large" number, and if  `var`  is a 1D decision variable, I would like to know if ipopt is more efficient at handling

```
-Inf < var < Inf
```

or

```
-10^12 < var < 10^12
```

From a practical standpoint, option 2) should be more efficient since it shrinks the design space, but if ipopt employs some smart heuristics to deal with `Inf` efficiently, it's possible that having to store and carry a ``large" number (e.g. `10^12`) becomes less efficient. Any insight?

Comment: My guess: no difference. I assume you tried it out.  BTW, your question implies you have a badly scaled model. You may want to work on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPOPT will be using different method for the two because in 1) the variable is unbounded, it is unconstrained, and in 2) the variable is bounded. The search space shrinks in 2), but IPOPT is more efficient at handling unconstrained/unbounded variables (1).